# I'm having trouble using the Model I wrote

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote a model like this:

```
List<School> schools = [
  School(city: "ISTANBUL", name: "Exam1"),
  School(city: "ISTANBUL", name: "Name2"),
  School(city: "ISTANBUL", name: "Name3")
];

List allSchools() {
  return schools;
}

class School {
  String city;
  String name;
  School({required this.city, required this.name});
}
```

I want to be able to use `city` and `name` values ​​in the list in Flutter.

Flutter codes:

```
  TextFieldSearch(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: "Select School",
      prefixIcon: const Icon(
        Icons.search,
        color: Colors.black45,
      ),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      ),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 229, 229, 229),
    ),
    initialList: allSchools(),
    label: "",
    controller: _schoolController,
  ),
```

How can I use model and list together? I hope you understand my point. Thanks in advance for your help.

---

Error

[image]

Comment: are you using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/textfield_search)?

Comment: Yes @eamirho3ein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [package](https://pub.dev/packages/textfield_search) you used only support one string, there is a workaround for that which is convert your `schools` list to a `newlist` like this:

```
List<String> newList = schools.map((e) => '${e.city}-${e.name}').toList();
```

and use this list to build your `TextFieldSearch`.

**For cleaner code** you can separate this widget like this:

```
Widget buildSearchField(List<School> schools) {
    List<String> newList = schools.map((e) => '${e.city}-${e.name}').toList();

    return TextFieldSearch(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: "Select School",
        prefixIcon: const Icon(
          Icons.search,
          color: Colors.black45,
        ),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        filled: true,
        fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 229, 229, 229),
      ),
      initialList: newList,
      label: "",
      controller: _schoolController,
    );
  }
```

and use it like this:

```
buildSearchField(allSchools()),
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I got an error like this => https://imgur.com/a/GJzrY9E

Comment: I can't see your image, could you edit your question and add there?

Comment: I did what you said and edited the question.

Comment: change this: `List allSchools() {` to this: `List<School> allSchools() {`